# How do I get xbox controls outside event loop in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, xbox

I use python3 and pygame and I have player class, in which I have my controls of the player defined as in the function:

```
    def get_input(self):
        #xbox example code, which doesnt work:
        buttons=pygame.joystick.Joystick.get_button()
        if buttons(button=0):
            self.jump()
        #more code for xbox controller. 
        #keyboard, this works perfectly:
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.direction.x = 1
        elif keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.direction.x = -1
        elif keys[pygame.K_d]:
            self.direction.x = 1
        elif keys[pygame.K_a]:
            self.direction.x = -1
        else:
            self.direction.x = 0
        if (keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]):
                self.direction.x = 0
        if (keys[pygame.K_SPACE] and self.on_ground):
            self.jump()
```

Question how do I add XBOX controls as in example above for the keys? (I wanna use axis for left-right movement and one button for jumping)
This code for reason I don't understand gives me following error:

```
File [...], line 37, in get_input
    buttons=pygame.joystick.Joystick.get_button()
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'get_button'
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create an instance object of a [`pygame.joystick.Joystick`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/joystick.html#pygame.joystick.Joystick).

Minimal example:

[image]

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((300, 300))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 20, 20)
rect.center = window.get_rect().center
vel = 5
color = (255, 0, 0)

joystick = None
if pygame.joystick.get_count() > 0:
    joystick = pygame.joystick.Joystick(0)
    joystick.init()
    print("joystick initialized")

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            print(pygame.key.name(event.key))

    if joystick:
        button = joystick.get_button(0)
        rect.x += round(joystick.get_axis(0) * vel)
        rect.y += round(joystick.get_axis(1) * vel)
        if joystick.get_button(0):
            color = (0, 255, 0)
        elif joystick.get_button(1):
            color = (255, 0, 0)
        elif joystick.get_button(2):
            color = (0, 0, 255)
        elif joystick.get_button(3):
            color = (255, 255, 0)

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    rect.x += (keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] - keys[pygame.K_LEFT]) * vel
    rect.y += (keys[pygame.K_DOWN] - keys[pygame.K_UP]) * vel
        
    rect.centerx = rect.centerx % window.get_width()
    rect.centery = rect.centery % window.get_height()

    window.fill(0)
    pygame.draw.rect(window, color, rect)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

Comment: @Von The problem is `pygame.joystick.Joystick.get_button()`. This does not work. You have to create an instance of the joystick. e.g.: `joystick = pygame.joystick.Joystick(0)`. Then you can get that buttons form that instance `buttons =  joystick.get_button()`.

Comment: Okey Thank you I know the reason, why this code didnt work. 
Reason was I didnt know I had to pass ''joystick'' to this function, which was in another file, if i intilize the joystick in the main file.